# Ruby: what's the difference with these self extensions?

Tags: ruby, module, extend, self

So I have three different ways I can have class level methods on a module:

I usually do it this way if I have 3 or fewer:

```
module Foo
  def self.speak
    "Foo"
  end
end
```

If I have more, I've traditionally done it this way:

```
module Bar
  class << self
    def speak
      "Bar"
    end
  end
end
```

But recently, I came across this nifty way and have started using this more often:

```
module FooBar
  extend self 

  def speak
    "FooBar"
  end
end
```

They all work:

```
Foo.speak => "Foo"
Bar.speak => "Bar"
FooBar.speak => "FooBar"
```

So, is there any material differences or gotchas to be aware of, esp. with the last form?  The only real gotcha I can think of is that once you "extend self" all method defs following are class-level.

I've tried to think of some edge cases where one form works, but the other doesn't.  Are there any?

Comment: using `extend` used to clear the [method cache](https://github.com/charliesome/charlie.bz/blob/master/posts/things-that-clear-rubys-method-cache.md) but as of 2.1, what clears the method cache has [changed](http://tmm1.net/ruby21-method-cache/).

Answer (score 3):

The third form, unlike the first two, creates both an instance method `:speak` and a module method `:speak`:

```
module Foo
  def self.speak
    "Foo"
  end
end
Foo.methods.include?(:speak)             #=> true
Foo.instance_methods.include?(:speak)    #=> false

class A
  include FooBar
end
A.instance_methods.include?(:speak)      #=> false
```

```
module Bar
  class << self
    def speak
      "Bar"
    end
  end
end
Bar.methods.include?(:speak)             #=> true
Bar.instance_methods.include?(:speak)    #=> false

class A
  include Bar
end
A.instance_methods.include?(:speak)      #=> false
```

```
module FooBar
  extend self 
  def speak
    "FooBar"
  end
end

FooBar.methods.include?(:speak)          #=> true
FooBar.instance_methods.include?(:speak) #=> true

class A
  include FooBar
end

A.instance_methods.include?(:speak)      #=> true
```